# I have problem for The Phusion Passenger when deploy reactjs web in to cpanel

Tags: passenger

/opt/cpanel/ea-ruby27/root/usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/node-loader.js:80
return originalRequire.apply(this, arguments);
^

Error [ERR_REQUIRE_ESM]: require() of ES Module /home/taliink1/public_html/frontend/app.js from /opt/cpanel/ea-ruby27/root/usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/node-loader.js not supported.
app.js is treated as an ES module file as it is a .js file whose nearest parent package.json contains "type": "module" which declares all .js files in that package scope as ES modules.
Instead rename app.js to end in .cjs, change the requiring code to use dynamic import() which is available in all CommonJS modules, or change "type": "module" to "type": "commonjs" in /home/taliink1/public_html/frontend/package.json to treat all .js files as CommonJS (using .mjs for all ES modules instead).

```
at Module.require (/opt/cpanel/ea-ruby27/root/usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/node-loader.js:80:25)
at loadApplication (/opt/cpanel/ea-ruby27/root/usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/node-loader.js:243:2)
at setupEnvironment (/opt/cpanel/ea-ruby27/root/usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/node-loader.js:214:2)
at Object.<anonymous> (/opt/cpanel/ea-ruby27/root/usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/node-loader.js:133:1) {
```

code: 'ERR_REQUIRE_ESM'
}

Comment: Did you found a solution to it ? I'm currently having the same issue.